# Vim syntax highlighting and certain characters

Tags: vim

I am attempting to write a syntax file for Vim.

One of the lines of code reads

```
syn match constant "\**\*"
```

while one of many other lines reads

```
syn keyword aiOperators up-build
```

The code for highlighting is the following:

```
hi constant gui=bold
hi aiOperators guifg=green
```

However, the result of the above is that only the following is highlighted:

- The asterisks of every **constant**, but not the characters between them.
- Characters up until the first hyphen of **aiOperators**.

What seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression for your constant specifies a literal asterisk, zero or more times, followed by a literal asterisk. If you intend to match characters delimited by asterisks, you need something like `\*\w\+\*`: a literal asterisk, followed by one or more word characters, followed by a literal asterisk.

The `:syn keyword` only works for keyword characters; by default, the hyphen is *not* included, so the match stops there. If, for your filetype, the hyphen belongs to the set of keyword characters, use

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

This should not be placed into the syntax file itself, but into `~/.vim/ftplugin/myfiletype.vim`. Otherwise, use `:syn match`.